# Using `mutate_at` or a `map` function in R to calculate distances between multiple locations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, r-sf

I have on dataframe (`controids`) with longitudes and latitudes for a set of locations:

```
library(tidyverse)

centroids <- 
  tribble(
    ~city, ~long, ~lat, 
    "A", -89.92702, 44.19367, 
    "B", -89.92525, 44.19654,
    "C", -89.92365, 44.19756, 
    "D", -89.91949, 44.19848, 
    "E", -89.91359, 44.19818)
```

I have a second dataframe (`towns`) with longitudes and latitudes for a second set of places.

```
towns <- 
  tribble(
    ~town, ~long, ~lat,
    "greentown", -89.92225, 44.19727,
    "bluetown", -89.92997, 44.19899,
    "redtown", -89.91500, 44.19600)
```

I want to add three columns to `centroids` giving the straight-line distance, in kilometers, between each city and  each of the three towns in `towns`. So the final dataframe would look like this (distances not correct, just for illustration):

```
output <- 
  tribble(
    ~city, ~long, ~lat, ~greentown_dist, ~bluetown_dist, ~redtown_dist,
    "A", -89.92702, 44.19367, 5.3, 2.0, 1.2,
    "B", -89.92525, 44.19654, 4.4, 2.3, 9.9,
    "C", -89.92365, 44.19756, 3.7, 5.4, 3.3,
    "D", -89.91949, 44.19848, 2.6, 3.9, 6.7,
    "E", -89.91359, 44.19818, 10.2, 2.2, 3.1)
```

I have to do this for a large number of towns so I'm trying to write some code that's easy to generalize. Here is what I have so far.

```
library(sf)

towns <- towns %>% st_as_sf(., coords=c('long', 'lat')) %>% st_geometry()

output <- 
  centroids %>% 
  st_as_sf(., coords=c('long', 'lat')) %>% 
  mutate(greentown_dist = st_distance(geometry, st_point(c( unlist(towns[1]) ))), 
         bluetown_dist = st_distance(geometry, st_point(c( unlist(towns[2]) ))), 
         redtown_dist = st_distance(geometry, st_point(c( unlist(towns[3]) ))))
```

I want to know if there's a way to do this using `mutate_at` and/or a `purrr` `map` function - one that fills in the TOWN_dist column name automatically and inputs the correct row from the `town` dataframe.

Comment: I think one way to something to what you want is to do a `full_join()` and then do your calculation then transpose with `pivot_wider`, `newdf <- full_join(centroids, towns, by = character())` this will give you one row per comparison

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` to loop over the 'towns'

```
centroids[paste0(c("green", "blue", "red"), "town_dist")] <- map(towns,
       ~ centroids %>% 
            st_as_sf(., coords = c('long', 'lat')) %>%
            transmute(dist = st_distance(geometry, st_point(c( unlist(.x))))))
```